# How to make the first element of a flex row a perfect square, with height of row dependent on content in other columns?

Tags: css, flexbox

Given a flex row, the idea is to make the first element a perfect square. The height of the flex row, however, should be determined by the content in the column.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first" data-this-should-be-a-square></div>

  <div data-this-element-should-determine-height-of-row>
    <p>dynamic content 1</p>
    <p>dynamic content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS which partially accomplishes this is

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px; /* Unwanted fixed height */
}

.first {
  background-color: black;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

however it does set a fixed height on the flex container. Is it possible to achieve a square first element without having to set the height?

Also tried using `height: 0` and `min-height: 100%` for the `.first` element, although it seems that they don't work unless a height is provided to the flex container.

Comment: How _high_ those other two columns need to be, depends on how _wide_ they will be (because that determines, where their content needs to break into another line) - but how wide they will be, depends on that first square to begin with, because if that gets wider, the remaining space to divide between the other two columns, also shrinks ... Bit of a catch-22.

Comment: @CBroe seems there's no way around this then. Thanks for your input. I'll close the q tomorrow unless you want to have your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using javascript for this, the following code gets the job done:

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  background-color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="first" data-this-should-be-a-square id="first"></div>
    
      <div data-this-element-should-determine-height-of-row id="dynamic">
        <p>dynamic content 1</p>
        <p>dynamic content 2</p>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/index.js" />
  </body>
```

Javascript:

```js
const dynamic = document.getElementById("dynamic");
const first = document.getElementById("first");

// To calculate the height of dynamic div
const setFirst = () => {
  let firstHeight = dynamic.clientHeight;
  first.style = `height: ${firstHeight}px; width: ${firstHeight}px`;
};

// We should manually run this once
dynamic.addEventListener("load", setFirst());

// MutationObserver API can be used to check if the contents of the dynamic div have changed.
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function () {
    setFirst();
  });
});

var config = { childList: true };

// Pass in the dynamic div, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(dynamic, config);

// This function is just to simulate the data change
const pushToDynmaic = () => {
  dynamic.innerHTML += "<p>dynamic content 2</p>";
};

setInterval(pushToDynmaic, 1000);
```

The result:
[image]